# How to get html contents of multiple spans and add the value as class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="inside">
   <ul class="fourcol first">
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span>0</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span>0</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span>1</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span>0</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span>1</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span>0</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span>1</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span>1</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span>0</span></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

```
<div class="inside">
   <ul class="fourcol first">
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span class="amenity-val-0">0</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span class="amenity-val-0">0</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span class="amenity-val-1">1</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span class="amenity-val-0">0</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span class="amenity-val-1">1</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span class="amenity-val-0">0</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span class="amenity-val-1">1</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span class="amenity-val-1">1</span></li>
       <li class="amenity-item">Something: <span class="amenity-val-0">0</span></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**My attempt:**

```
$(function() {

    var value_of_span = $.each('span.amenity-val').html()

    if (value_of_span == 0) {
        $('span.amenity-val').addClass('amenity-val-0');
    }

    if (value_of_span == 1) {
        $('span.amenity-val').addClass('amenity-val-1');
    }

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

1) `$.each()` to loop through all the `span` element inside `.amenity-item`:

2) `text()` to get the text inside your span

3) `addClass()` to add the class based on the retrieved text respectively

```
$.each($('.amenity-item span'), function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass('amenity-val-' + text);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DM3Y4/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vYQKH/2/)

```
$('span').each(function() {
    var x = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass('amenity-val-' + x);
});
```

This will iterate over each span tag, grab it's text and save it as var x, and then  we just simply add the class to that span.